# VF commandButton to update field

Tags: commandbutton

I am trying to build a time clock in SF and can't seem to figure out how to use the commandButton to update the 'Clocked In' on the custom object. I have built the VF page and added the button but can't seem to get the action to work. Any suggestions?

Here is the code for the Clock In button -

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Time Clock"> 
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:form >
            <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Clock_Status__c}"/>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>

    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
        <apex:form >
            <apex:commandButton style="float:left; width:300px; border-radius:7px 7px 7px 7px; vertical-align:center; margin-left:-25%; height:100px; padding:20px; color:#ffffff; font-size:30px; background:#3ECF43; text-decoration:none;" value="Clock In"/>
            <apex:commandButton style="float:left; width:300px; border-radius:7px 7px 7px 7px; height:100px; margin-right: 0px; margin-left:30px; padding:20px; color:#ffffff; font-size:30px; background:#FA2D30; text-decoration:none;" value="Clock Out"/>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Can you please edit your original question to contain the code that you currently have for this, and any errors that you are receiving if there are any?

Answer (score 1):

If the clock status is an input on the page, you could probably get away with simply calling the default "save" action. If you want to use your two buttons and change the field to output only, you will need to add two methods to your controller and then as the action property on the buttons. One that sets the value to clocked in and saves, another that sets it to clocked out and saves.

Comment: Is it possible to also insert the current date and time into a field in a custom object using the same buttons?

Comment: With the custom action route? Yes. For the default save to do that then we would need to get into triggers as well.

Comment: Ok, I'm new at this so I appreciate the help.  I think I should start with simply updating the status when the button is clicked. How does the system know who is clocking in and out? I assume there needs to be some validation?